# Google Apps Script: Format Date of DateBox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Hello I am new to Google Apps Script and programing in general.

I would like to know if I can create a custom date format for the way a date appears when selected in a DateBox.

I read somewhere to use "Utilities.formatDate()" but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I tried: (I used the formating code for the date only as an example. I would rather have something like "MMM-DD-YYYY" or "MMM-YY")

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

var grdProjDates = app.createGrid(3,5).setId('GRDprojDates');
grdProjDates.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Satrting Date'));
grdProjDates.setWidget(0, 4, app.createDateBox().setId('DateProjEnd')
                                                .setName('DateProjEnd')
                                                .setFormat(formattedDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the setFormat option on the datebox itself, e.g.

`app.createDateBox().setId("FormDate").setValue(Today).setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.YEAR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY);`

as referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-time-format).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I would really like is to create my own custom format, for example "Apr-13". I also tried the setFormat option but it seems that I am only limited to the formats referenced in that page. Is there a way I can modify them?

Comment: Should be possible, these are just pre-defined constants after all. But I myself haven't worked that one out yet - so open it up to others to chime in with suggestions....

Comment: No, it's not possible. Unfortunately we're limited by the constants provided.